# Native ActionBar-based tabs with native fragments (with MvvmCross)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am porting an Xamarin-based Android app to be PCL'ified and MvvmCross'ified so we can target multiple mobile device platforms.

Since this is a line-of-business app where we can dictate the minimum Android OS version, we wish to *avoid* using the various v4 / v7 etc "Support libraries". We prefer to use all native components that are already part of the OS. So this basically means we only wish to target Jellybean and probably Android v4.2 upwards.

Unfortunately whilst there are lots of examples out there of using MvvmCross with `ActionBarSherlock` and the `SupportActionBar` (in a support library), there appears to be no examples of how to wire up MvvmCross with the native `ActionBar` using native `Fragment`s as tabs.

I'm not expecting someone to post up swathes of code but would really appreciate if someone could give me a few pointers on the best approach to take to achieve this.

I will certainly blog about it once I have a working solution to benefit the whole MvvmCross/Xamarin community.

Thanks.

Comment: I notice there is a relatively new extension for MvvmCross called "FullFragging" which appears to implement the necessary Mvx pieces for supporting native Fragments (Ice Cream Sandwich and up). However the `MvxTabsFragmentActivity` appears to be based upon the highly legacy and deprecated `TabHost` control. Seems odd, unless I'm misunderstanding something. Perhaps the overall solution then is to simply copy the source from this and refactor it towards using native ActionBar instead?

Comment: The SupportLibraries are mainly there for earlier android versions (although some do extend newer os flavours too). There are quite a lot of full app samples on github now. For one example of ActionBar use, try https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MeetupManager/blob/master/MeetupManager.Droid/Helpers/MvxActionBarActivity.cs

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most important thing is to use [MvvmCross - Hot Tuna Droid **Full** Fragment Support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.FullFragging/3.1.1) NUGet library. Then create activity that inherits from MvxActivity and fragment from MvxFragment.

ViewModel for tab fragment set in activity when create this class for TabEventArgs.FragmentTransaction.Add method used in ActionBar.Tab.TabSelected event handler like this:

```
var tab1 = new TabFragment1 {DataContext = ViewModel};
```

In TabFragment1 class you can use standard fluent binding method on bindingSet creted by

```
var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<TabFragment1, MyViewModel>();
```

I don't know if it is a right way, but work.